# Revert the given permission to Storage Access API on Safari

Tags: safari, storage-access-api

I am working with [Storage Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API) on Safari.

For testing/debugging purposes, I want to take back the permission that I've previously given. Currently, I keep creating new loopback IPs which is a bit annoying (see screencap below), also I need to give instructions to the testing team once this is deployed to prod.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A year late but for anyone who sees this wondering how to reset the flow: go to Safari Privacy Settings and click the Manage Website Data button, remove the website data that you would like (or remove all), and quit Safari. The next time you launch and go to the website that requires access it should start the flow from the beginning.